# The copy process is very slow with this function vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I use this function for copying some files from the Source folder to the Destination folder, but the copying is needed more time than usual.

```
 Sub SyncFiles(Lbl_Percentage As Label, Lbl_FileName As Label, PrgrsBar As ProgressBar)
    Try

        Dim Sql As String = "SELECT GroupID FROM Tbl_Current"
        Dim GetGroupID = MsAcc_RetriveTemp(Sql, 0)

        Dim Sql1 As String = "Select * FROM Tbl_SyncPath where ID=" & GetGroupID
        Dim Src As String = MsAcc_RetriveTemp(Sql1, 1)
        Dim Des As String = MsAcc_RetriveTemp(Sql1, 2)


        If Not IO.Directory.Exists(Des) Then IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Des)
        Dim fls() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(Des)
        PrgrsBar.Value = 0
        PrgrsBar.Maximum = fls.Count

        For Each fn As String In fls

            Dim filename As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(fn)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Des, Src, True)
            PrgrsBar.Value += 1 'add 1 to the ProgressBar`s value 

            Dim Percntge As Integer = (PrgrsBar.Value / fls.Count) * 100
            Lbl_Percentage.Text = Percntge & " %"
            Lbl_FileName.Text = "جاري تحديث ملف:  " & filename
            Application.DoEvents()
            Lbl_FileName.Text = "اكتمل عملية التحديث."
        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Somehow you are confusing source with destination. "Source" is where you get the files from. "Destination" is where you put the files to.

Comment: I don't think the loop is necessary. Just the one line `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory("C:\TestDirectory1", "C:\TestDirectory2", True)' The first parameter is the current location of the files. The second parameter is where you want to copy the files to. You are copying the directory over and over. Getting rid of the loop should speed things up considerably

Answer (score 0):

You copy all the files in the folder for each files.

```
    For Each fn As String In fls

        Dim filename As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(fn)

        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Des, Src, True) ' <--- No file specified
        PrgrsBar.Value += 1 'add 1 to the ProgressBar`s value 

        Dim Percntge As Integer = (PrgrsBar.Value / fls.Count) * 100
        Lbl_Percentage.Text = Percntge & " %"
        Lbl_FileName.Text = "جاري تحديث ملف:  " & filename
        Application.DoEvents()
        Lbl_FileName.Text = "اكتمل عملية التحديث."
    Next
```

Put this outside the loop

```
    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Des, Src, True)

    For Each fn As String In fls
        ' ...
    Next
```

Also, seems like des and src are mixed up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I change the code as you said, but the files doesn't copy to destination.